# Redirect preserving query strings

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, parameters

I want to all my request to `www.example.com/original-link` go to `www.newsite.com` but preserving original query strings and adding some more

Example:

`www.example.com/original-link?param_request=value1`

Go to

```
www.newsite.com?param_request=value1&new_param=value2
```

Comment: I tried this: 

RewriteRule /original-link https://www.newsite.com?new_param=value2 [L,QSA]

Comment: It would be helpful to know what Webserver you're using. I guess you're using Apache, but being explicit also never hurts. Also you say you tried a `RewriteRule`, did that work? If not, what behaviour did you observe instead of the intended?

Answer (score 1):

php solution:

```
header('Location: http.//www.newsite.com?param_request='
            . $value1 . '&new_param=' .$value2);
die();
```

`$value1` is usually computed by $_GET[]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess of old site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^original-link/?$ http://newsite.com?new_param=value2 [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: I dont know why is not wokring.Should I create a file with name `original-link.php` or `original-link.html`?

Comment: This should work if URL is `www.example.com/original-link?param_request=value1`. Make sure this your top most rule and .htaccess is enabled.